# Find by or create from API rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

Trying to create a Rails belongs to association from an API

**Person Model**

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Donation Model**

```
class Donation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
end
```

**DonationsController**

```
def create
  person = Person.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if person.nil?
    Person.create(email: params[:email], prenom: params[:prenom],
                  nom: params[:nom], address: params[:address], code_postal: params[:code_postal],
                  ville: params[:ville], pays: params[:pays], mobile: params[:mobile])
    person
   #return person_id
  end

  @donation = Donation.create(donation_params.merge(person_id: person.id))
  render json: @donation
end
```

I would like to return the person.id of the person who was just created before creating the donation

Comment: i think you can get it by using `@donation.person.id` after creation of `@donation`.

Comment: lets try the given solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create
  @person = Person.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if @person.blank?
    @person = Person.create(email: params[:email], prenom: params[:prenom],
                  nom: params[:nom], address: params[:address], code_postal: params[:code_postal],
                  ville: params[:ville], pays: params[:pays], mobile: params[:mobile])

  end

  @donation = Donation.create(donation_params.merge(person_id: @person.id))
  #render json: @donation
  render :json => { donations: @donation, :person_id => @person.id }
end
```

Comment: @Benjamin feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. :)